# Magento 2 : Cannot disable page cache of Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, product-view, full-page-cache

Tried to set `cacheable="false"` in a block in `catalog_product_view.xml`. But the product detail page is still being cached.
I just want to disable the cache of the Product Detail Page. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.